# How to access a JSON in a column in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset which has one column that contains JSON data as shown below, I'm using the Pandas library.

[Table with JSON data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZFAw.png)

What would be the easiest method to access the JSON? For example I would like to see how many views A has produced.

Answer (score 0):

```
fields = ['Actions']

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', skipinitialspace=True, usecols=fields) #df would now contain all your json under actions.
```

Or

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', skipinitialspace=True)
print df['Actions']
```